# Excel VBA working with cell inside a table given its range

Tags: vba, excel, range, listobject

I have just started working with VBA for an internship, and I am having a small issue with my current project. I am certain this is a straight forward fix I am not seeing as there is nothing online for it.

My worksheet takes a couple of input values in a list objects row, and returns the relevant values from the mapping to the other columns in the same row.

I want it to only run the FindBankInfo sub for the row which the user has changed

```
If Not Intersect(Target, lo.ListColumns("Document Type").Range) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, lo.ListColumns("Bank").Range) Is Nothing _
Or Not Intersect(Target, lo.ListColumns("Transit Type").Range) Is Nothing Then
'rowCount in the sub is used as lo.listrow(rowcount), it's the table row I am working with
    FindBankInfo lo, loMap, loMap2, rowCount
End If
```

I can make this work like this

```
If Not Intersect(Target, lo.ListColumns("Document Type").Range) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, lo.ListColumns("Bank").Range) Is Nothing _
Or Not Intersect(Target, lo.ListColumns("Transit Type").Range) Is Nothing Then
    For Each lr in lo.ListRows
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        FindBankInfo lo, loMap, loMap2, rowCount
    Next lr
End If
```

Like this it's going through every row each time something gets changed and in the sub I skip if it's already populated. But this feels dumb and inefficient, and gets slow if there is a lot of rows as I am checking for blank rows in between populated rows, so I can't just end on blank.

What I need is given a Target, how can I convert that Target range to the relevant ListObject Range and get the ListObject row number???

Target.ListObject gives me the appropriate range for my table so I know it can touch it, and I can get the exact range I want to interact with, but the row number is relevant to the sheets rowcount and not the tables. I would really appreciate some guidance, thanks.

Comment: I'm not following exactly because I don't see the rest of your code, but check out target.row for a start...

Comment: I will have to edit the question later on then, I apologize. As for Target.row, it will give me the absolute row, but not the row relevant to the table. To make that clearer, if my table starts at A5, then the secound row in the table counting header is A7. Target.row will give me 7. But for lo.Listrow(index) it is not 7, the index would be 2. Again sorry for the lack of clarity, I'll edit when I get home.

Comment: Your `FindBankInfo` seems like a subrouting but I imagine it could easily be changed to a function. Why not just use it as a UDF and place it as a formula on the proper column rather than have a script run through your whole sheet, find the row you are looking for and then write the value?

Comment: Then Target.row - lo.range.row will get you 2

Comment: Not sure if you got your answer but if your table is static, you can name you table.range. You can then get the row within that range. Have a look at 'Naming a range in excel'

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help guys, I looked at everything and rewrote it into functions. I am a complete noob I don't know why I didn't go that route in the first place. I didn't conceptualize the functionality of UDFs, all the other answers helped as well so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your subroutine into a UDF and use as a formula on your Table.